# How to connect to mysql database in phonegap

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, cordova

Can anyone show me an example of how to connect to mysql database in phonegap or if its even possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with cgwyllie you should write a webservice which will act as an API to your database with methods returning JSON (or XML).

The webservice methods can then be called from your PhoneGap project (I would recommend having a look at the jquery ajax api http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

I would just write the webservice in PHP or whatever language you are familiar with.

Comment: thanks for the link that really helped me out.